# status (pending) Type xhr

Tags: javascript, axios

### Pending request

Guys, I've been looking for an answer to this error for days and I can't find it. Whenever I make the request to the server, some are sent to the database, with the status (204) and others (most) with status (pending).

**Server code**

```js
router.post("/planilha-clientes", (req, res) => {
  const {
    nome,
    nome_abreviado,
    codigo,
    grupo,
    cnpj,
    status,
    pais,
    estado,
    cidade,
    bairro,
    endereco,
    lat,
    long,
  } = req.body;

  criarTable();

  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO clientes (nome, nome_abreviado, codigo, grupo, cnpj, status, pais, estado, cidade, bairro, endereco, lat, longi) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    [
      nome, nome_abreviado, codigo, grupo, cnpj, status, pais, estado, cidade, bairro, endereco, lat, long
    ],
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        console.log('Dados adicionados para a tabela clientes!')
      }
    }
  );
});
```

**Client Code**

```js
const enviarPlanilha = async () => {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < items.length) {
      Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/planilha-clientes', {
        nome: items[i].NOME,
        nome_abreviado: items[i].NOME_ABREVIADO,
        codigo: items[i].CÓDIGO,
        grupo: items[i].GRUPO,
        cnpj: items[i].CNPJ,
        status: items[i].STATUS,
        pais: items[i].PAÍS,
        estado: items[i].ESTADO,
        cidade: items[i].CIDADE,
        bairro: items[i].BAIRRO,
        endereco: items[i].ENDEREÇO,
        lat: items[i].LAT,
        long: items[i].LONG
      })
      i++;
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router function never calls `res.send`, `res.json`, or any of the other methods on the response object that would cause it to send a response.

Since the client never gets a response to any of its requests, it will be forever pending (until it gives up and throws a timeout error).

Comment: This is not the complete code. Where do I have to call res.send?

Comment: Somewhere inside the callback you pass to router.post